# How to decode UTF-8 knowing character count but not byte count?

Tags: swift, encoding, utf-8

I need to decode a UTF-8-encoded string I don’t know the byte count for. I do know the character count.

With the byte count, I would do this:

```
NSString(bytes:    UnsafePointer<Byte>(bytes),
         length:   byteCount,
         encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

How can I use the character count instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the UTF-8 `UnicodeCodec` to decode
bytes until the wanted number of characters is reached
(or an error occurs):

```
func decodeUTF8<S: Sequence>(bytes: S, numCharacters: Int) -> String
    where S.Iterator.Element == UInt8 {
        var iterator = bytes.makeIterator()
        var utf8codec = UTF8()
        var string = ""
        while string.characters.count < numCharacters {
            switch (utf8codec.decode(&iterator)) {
            case let .scalarValue(val):
                string.unicodeScalars.append(val)
            default:
                // Error or out of bytes:
                return string
            }
        }
        return string
}
```

(You could also return `nil` or throw an error in the error case.)

Example:

```
let bytes = "H€llo".utf8
let dec = decodeUTF8(bytes: bytes, numCharacters: 3)
print(dec)  // H€l
```

Comment: Seems replacing
`while string.characters.count < numCharacters`
with
`for _ in 1...numCharacters`
will make this much faster.

Comment: @Pal: That might be. On the other hand, there is no 1-1 correspondence between unicode scalars and characters, so the result could be too short. – Try the above example with `let bytes = "Hllo".utf8`

Comment: I see. But it seems that evaluating `string.characters.count` takes a lot of time… So here’s what I’m doing now: `for _ in 1...numCharacters { […] }`, then, in order to take care of any leftovers: `while string.characters.count < numCharacters { […] }`. Is this OK?

Comment: @Pal: It should, can't think of a case where that would fail. But I would write it as `for _ in 0..<numCharacters`, otherwise it crashes if called with `numCharacters = 0`.